# Logging in with either username or email

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am writing an admin check to make sure that the email that is logging into the admin area is:

- An admin user
- Is active

I have so far written the following code:

**Controller:**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userName','userName', 'required|trim|max_length[99]|callback_admin_check|xss_clean');

function _admin_check($adminUsername, $adminEmail)
            {
                if($this->users_model->admin_check($adminUsername) || $this->users_model->admin_check($adminEmail))
                {
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('admin_check', 'Sorry you have an %s error!');
                    return FALSE;
                }else{
                    return TRUE;
                }
```

What I am confused about here is that I would like it to accept both the admin username or email address if the `userGroup == admin` or if the account is `userActive == yes` but I am unsure how I would construct the model to or what data to send through to the model.

**Update -> Joe:**

Joe,

Just a couple of questions:

- Do I still set my validation error messages where it `return false`?
- Is there anyway that I could check that the account is  an **admin account** and is **active**?
- Is the Model OK?

**Controller:**

```
function _admin_check($adminUsername = null, $adminEmail = null)
    {
        $adminUser = $this->user_model->admin_check($adminUsername,$adminEmail);

        //if the UN || PW are not correct

        if(! $adminUser)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE); // Does not bother adding incorrect data into the session for the Admin Login
            $this->form_validation->set_message('admin_check', 'Sorry you have a %s error!');
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            //Set the session data
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userId',$adminUser->id);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userFirstName',$adminUser->userFirstName);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userLastName',$adminUser->userLastName);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userEmail',$adminUser->userEmail);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userGroup',$adminUser->userGroup);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userActive',$adminUser->userActive);
            return TRUE;
        }
```

**Model:**

```
            function admin_check($adminUsername, $adminEmail)
    {
            if(is_null($adminUsername && is_null($adminEmail)))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            if(is_null($adminUsername))
            {
                $login_field = 'userEmail';
                $login_name = '$adminEmail';
            }else{
                $login_field = 'userName';
                $login_name = '$adminUsername'
            }

            $this->db->select($login_field,$login_name);
            $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->where('userName', $adminUsername , 'userEmail' , $adminEmail );
            $query = $this->db-get();

            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the defaults for both parameters to null: `function _admin_check($adminUsername = null, $adminEmail = null)`

Then at the top of the method in the model, add this:

```
function admin_check($adminUsername = null, $adminEmail = null)
{
    if (is_null($adminUsername) && is_null($adminEmail))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (is_null($adminUsername))
    {
        $login_field = 'email'; // field in the table
        $login_name = $adminEmail; // value of the field
    }
    else
    {
        $login_field = 'username';
        $login_name = $adminUsername;
    }

    // Your SQL here, using $login_field and $login_name
```

To call with the username, call like this:

```
$this->users_model->admin_check($adminUsername);
$this->users_model->admin_check($adminUsername, null); // or this
```

And for the email

```
$this->users_model->admin_check(null, $adminEmail);
```

To call it in one:

```
$this->users_model->admin_check($adminUsername, $adminEmail);
```

Comment: The code I wrote was for the model (`admin_check`), not the controller (`_admin_check`) :P The idea is that you can do `$this->db->where($login_field, $login_name)` and it'll use the correct non-null login value :)

Comment: Joe thanks,  I know that this has possibly been done but by doing that way I do not learn,  I have updated the question am I on the correct track now?

Comment: Joe,  I have just updated my controller but I am unsure how I can check that the account login in is admin or is active do I write another if statement in the model?

Comment: What do you mean by "active"? As for checking if it's an admin, presumably you have a column like `is_admin` in your table which is Boolean, so just add it into your `$this->db->select()` call

Comment: Joe,  At the moment this is my DB structure http://cl.ly/2l2v3T113M0X0B1w0K3k  I have 2 rows userActive yes/no - I should really change this to a Boolean and I have userGroup witch is admin/user I want to check if the email entered is admin if not false or is active if not false

Comment: It does sound like quite a basic thing you're struggling with, but essentially what you want to do is: (1) add the `userGroup` and `userActive` columns to your `$this->db->select()` (2) run a couple of `if ()` statements to test the values of those columns, and (3) store the results in the array you `return` from the `admin_check()` method in the model

Answer (score 3):

You can create the method of the model to receive 2 parameters, that is the username and the email.

```
function admin_check($username = NULL, $email = NULL)
```

Now, if you want to check by using username, simply call the function like `admin_check($username)`. But if you want to check by email, you can pass `NULL` as the first parameter, and the email as the second one.

Then inside the function, create an `if` statement to check whether the first parameter is `NULL`. If so, do the check by using the email address. Otherwise, use the username to do the check.

```
if ($username === NULL)
{
    // use the email address to do the authentication
}
else
{
    // use $username instead 
}
```